# Transitions between different HTML pages using JQTouch for iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, jqtouch

I am trying to create a simple iPhone application using HTML/JavaScript/CSS with the help of JQTouch and PhoneGap. For accessing different parts of a web page, the transitions work fine, however when I try to do the same for different web pages, they do not work.

I am doing this:

```
 <li><a class="slide" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/remysharp/3047035327/" title="Tall Glow"><img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3011/3047035327_ca12fb2397_s.jpg" height="75" width="75" alt="Tall Glow" /></a></li>
```

Does anyone knwo whats wrong pleasE?

C.

Comment: it works if the page is not external (in other words not rel="external")

Comment: in this case it wasn't necessary to specify it but was treated that way all the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqtouch can only slide in divs, i.e. parts of a single web page. when you follow links it just loads whatever page you navigated to.

Answer (score 0):

You should try loading your external link in an IFRAME. As long as the site you are linking to doesn't have a frame buster, you should be able to stay on your own site and display the content of the external page.